# Angular.js: Unexpected token < and module injection error after updating bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I updated angular in bower from 1.3.8 to 1.4.3 and now no matter what I try, I get these two errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.js:38
>
> Uncaught Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…Flocalhost%3A8084%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A339)

Comment: Did you update all Google proprietary AngularJS bower components? as well i.e. angular-cookies, angular-sanitize, angular-messages etc would most likely need to be updated to 1.4.3 as well

Comment: Yes. I also downgraded them again to what was the original working configuration, and the problem persists. I must be doing something really dumb but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Are you accidentally rewriting the requested url to return html? If you are building a SPA, you might be returning an index.html page to bootstrap your app due to a bad src tag url.

Comment: It's gotta be something like that with one of my packages' dependencies but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by Angulartics which I accidentally upgraded to a version that had different  dependencies.

http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/